# Arranging array accending

Tags: java

Aim is to get an array and arrange it accending, and print

```
package habeeb; 
import java.util.*;
public class Habeeb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = new int[10];
        int i, count=0, m;
        System.out.println("Enter the integers, with 0 to end the array" );
        for( i=0; i<num.length; i++){
            num[i]= input.nextInt();
```

Zero breaks the array here

```
            if(num[i]==0)
            break;
            count++;
```

Calling the function here\

```
        }
        Sorting(num, count);
```

The function sorting is here

```
    }
    public static void Sorting(int[] sort, int con){
        if(con<0)
            return;
        int j, max=0, coun=0, temp;
        for(j=0; j<con; j++){
            if(sort[j]>max)
                max=sort[j];
            coun=j;
        }
```

here am swaping the last value in the array for any index thats the highest

```
        temp=sort[con];
        sort[con]=sort[coun];
        sort[coun]=temp;
```

Calling the function again here(recursive)

```
        Sorting(sort, con-1);
```

Here am printing, why is it not printing

```
        for(j=0; j<con; j++){
            System.out.println(sort[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to reformat your code and use regular java comments.

Comment: Is there a good reason to not use Arrays.sort?  When you step through your code in your debugger what do you see?

Comment: Debugging is almost easier as asking and you get much more!

Comment: can you please help me apply the Array.sort, and help me modify my program. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason not to use [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29) ?

All you have to do is call

```
Arrays.sort(num);
```

Be careful since this will **modify** your array and will not create a sorted coyp of it!